# right path to a file in google glass memory

Tags: android, google-glass

As a Google Glass developer, how can I reach the internal storage of the Glass?

I tried:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                 + File.separator + "/DCIM/test.jpg");
```

but it doesn't work.

I want to be able to reach the photos and videos inside the device.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the `MediaStorage` API?

Answer (score 1):

You should use (note the missing **"/"** at the begging):

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                 + File.separator + "DCIM/Camera/test.jpg");
```

An example path of a picture in the Glass storage is like:

*/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20140530_181813_833.jpg*

you can get it with:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "DCIM/Camera/20140530_181813_833.jpg");
```

Comment: I am getting the directory. But when i check `picturefile.exists()` it fails. where `picturefile = New File(picutrePath)`

Comment: if you are getting the image path from camera onactivityresult. You  should wait for the image to be ready. Check: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/camera#images

Comment: you are right...the image was taking time to get ready..now i am using thumbnail image for temporarily :) thanks..